# MDX Eariest Date in a set

Tags: date, mdx

I am trying to obtain the row with the first date based on the following data pull with the filters I have applied.  The query below has duplicates for the "Parent Incident ID" Key what I want is the earliest date within the filtered parameters below for "Modified By ID" starting with "N" and etc. Thanks for any help.

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Count of Assignee Reassignments]} ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY 
   {
     (
      [Related Assignee History].[Modified By Id].[Modified By Id].ALLMEMBERS
     *[Related Assignee History].[Parent Incident Id].[Parent Incident Id].ALLMEMBERS
     *[Related Assignee History].[Start Date Time].[Start Date Time].AllMembers
     )
   } 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 

FROM(
    SELECT
       (
         Filter(
           [Related Assignee History].[Modified By Id].Children
          ,Left([Related Assignee History].[Modified By Id].CurrentMember.Name,1)="n"
         )
       ) ON COLUMNS 
     FROM(
         SELECT
           (
             { [Incident].[Owner Group].&[Directors Group]}) ON COLUMNS 
         FROM(
             SELECT
               (
                 {[Incident].[Reported Source].&[Self Service]}) ON COLUMNS 
             From(
                 Select
                    (
                       {[Related Assignee History].[Start Date Time].ITEM(0)}) on columns
                 FROM(
                     SELECT({[Date Reported].[Year].&[2016] }) ON COLUMNS 
                     FROM [Incident]
                   )
                )
             )
         )
      );
```

Results look like this:

```
David   123456  1/5/2016 10:03:29 AM    1
David   111111  2/9/2016 10:05:31 AM    1
Samuel  123456  2/9/2016 10:07:01 AM    1
Samuel  111111  1/6/2016 12:03:29 AM    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Step-by-step (hopefully!)

1.Initially I would start by simplifying by deleting quite a few braces:

```
SELECT 
 NON EMPTY 
   [Measures].[Count of Assignee Reassignments] ON 0, 
 NON EMPTY 
    [Related Assignee History].[Modified By Id].[Modified By Id].ALLMEMBERS
   *[Related Assignee History].[Parent Incident Id].[Parent Incident Id].ALLMEMBERS
   *[Related Assignee History].[Start Date Time].[Start Date Time].ALLMEMBERS
FROM(
    SELECT
       FILTER(
           [Related Assignee History].[Modified By Id].Children
          ,Left([Related Assignee History].[Modified By Id].CurrentMember.Name,1)="n"
       ) ON 0 
     FROM(
         SELECT
           [Incident].[Owner Group].&[Directors Group] ON 0 
         FROM(
             SELECT
               [Incident].[Reported Source].&[Self Service] ON 0 
             FROM(
                 SELECT
                    [Related Assignee History].[Start Date Time].ITEM(0) ON 0
                 FROM
                   (
                     SELECT [Date Reported].[Year].&[2016] ON 0 
                     FROM   [Incident]
                   )
                )
             )
         )
      );
```

2.If you're only interested in `[Date Reported].[Year].&[2016]` then lets move it out of the crazy nested subselects into a `WHERE` clause - similarly lets move the Incidents members into this `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT 
 NON EMPTY 
   [Measures].[Count of Assignee Reassignments] ON 0, 
 NON EMPTY 
    [Related Assignee History].[Modified By Id].[Modified By Id].ALLMEMBERS
   *[Related Assignee History].[Parent Incident Id].[Parent Incident Id].ALLMEMBERS
   *[Related Assignee History].[Start Date Time].[Start Date Time].ALLMEMBERS
FROM
   (
    SELECT
       FILTER(
           [Related Assignee History].[Modified By Id].Children
          ,Left([Related Assignee History].[Modified By Id].CurrentMember.Name,1)="n"
       ) ON 0 
    FROM
       (
        SELECT
          [Related Assignee History].[Start Date Time].ITEM(0) ON 0
        FROM [Incident]
       ) 
   )
WHERE 
 ([Date Reported].[Year].&[2016]
 ,[Incident].[Owner Group].&[Directors Group]
 ,[Incident].[Reported Source].&[Self Service]);
```

3.Now lets moVe the Filter into a `WITH` clause and use the `Member_Caption` property to find names that begin with N such as Nathaniel -we will then use the named set in the `SELECT` clause:

```
WITH 
  SET [N_names] AS
     FILTER(
           [Related Assignee History].[Modified By Id].[Modified By Id].MEMBERS
          ,Left([Related Assignee History].[Modified By Id].CurrentMember.MEMBER_CAPTION,1) = 'N'
     )
SELECT 
 NON EMPTY 
   [Measures].[Count of Assignee Reassignments] ON 0, 
 NON EMPTY 
    [N_names]
   *[Related Assignee History].[Parent Incident Id].[Parent Incident Id].ALLMEMBERS
   *[Related Assignee History].[Start Date Time].[Start Date Time].ALLMEMBERS
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      [Related Assignee History].[Start Date Time].ITEM(0) ON 0
    FROM [Incident]
  ) 
WHERE 
 ([Date Reported].[Year].&[2016]
 ,[Incident].[Owner Group].&[Directors Group]
 ,[Incident].[Reported Source].&[Self Service]);
```

4.I'm guessing that this `[Related Assignee History].[Start Date Time].ITEM(0)` is your attempt to find the min date for each person so I will delete that for the time-being:

```
WITH 
  SET [N_names] AS
     FILTER(
           [Related Assignee History].[Modified By Id].[Modified By Id].MEMBERS
          ,Left([Related Assignee History].[Modified By Id].CurrentMember.MEMBER_CAPTION,1) = 'N'
     )
SELECT 
 NON EMPTY 
   [Measures].[Count of Assignee Reassignments] ON 0, 
 NON EMPTY 
    [N_names]
   *[Related Assignee History].[Parent Incident Id].[Parent Incident Id].ALLMEMBERS
   *[Related Assignee History].[Start Date Time].[Start Date Time].ALLMEMBERS
FROM [Incident]
WHERE 
 ([Date Reported].[Year].&[2016]
 ,[Incident].[Owner Group].&[Directors Group]
 ,[Incident].[Reported Source].&[Self Service]);
```

5.Now it gets a bit more complicated:

```
WITH 
  SET [N_names] AS
     FILTER(
           [Related Assignee History].[Modified By Id].[Modified By Id].MEMBERS
          ,Left([Related Assignee History].[Modified By Id].CurrentMember.MEMBER_CAPTION,1) = 'N'
     )
  SET [N_names_plusDates] AS
     GENERATE(
        [N_names] AS N
        ,   N.CURRENTMEMBER
          * TAIL(
               NONEMPTY(
                 [Related Assignee History].[Start Date Time].[Start Date Time].MEMBERS
                ,N.CURRENTMEMBER
               )
             )
     )
SELECT 
 NON EMPTY 
   [Measures].[Count of Assignee Reassignments] ON 0, 
 NON EMPTY 
    [N_names_plusDates]
   *[Related Assignee History].[Parent Incident Id].[Parent Incident Id].ALLMEMBERS
FROM [Incident]
WHERE 
 ([Date Reported].[Year].&[2016]
 ,[Incident].[Owner Group].&[Directors Group]
 ,[Incident].[Reported Source].&[Self Service]);
```